# Waypoints in WordPress theme only works when Developer's tool is opened

Tags: wordpress, jquery-waypoints

I'm trying to include Waypoints (http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) in my WordPress theme without using their plugin (premium plugin).
So, I downloaded the necessary files and enqueued them:

```
    // Waypoints
    wp_enqueue_script( 'waypoints-main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/waypoint/jquery.waypoints.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'waypoints-animations', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/waypoints-animations.js', array( 'jquery', 'waypoints-main' ), false, true );
```

This is what I have in my waypoints-animations.js file:

```
(function($){

var $div1 = $('.new-arrivals');

$div1.waypoint(function(direction){
    if (direction === 'down'){
        $div1.addClass('animate');
    } else{
        $div1.removeClass('animate');
    }
}, 
    {offset: '60%'}
);
})(window.jQuery)
```

My CSS says this:

```
.new-arrivals {
    clear: both;
    padding: 40px 0 0 0;
    margin-bottom: -40px;
    transition: 1s;
    opacity: 0;
}

.animate {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

I don't have errors in my console. But I noticed that the page is loading with the direction set to 'down', causing the div with the class .new-arrivals to display by default (opacity 1). I want the opposite to happen.
Once I managed to make the code function, but that only happened when the developer's tool was opened. I couldn't understand why that happened...
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Just managed to find the mistake.
I needed to add the scroll event. Like this:

```
(function ($) {
    var $div1 = $('.new-arrivals');
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        $div1.waypoint(function (direction) {
            if (direction === 'down') {
                $div1.addClass('animate');
            } else {
                $div1.removeClass('animate');
            }
        }, {
            offset: '60%'
        });
    });
})(window.jQuery)
```